# MySql.Data, could not be resolved because it was built against the another version

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I am trying to create my first .NET app to connect to mysql data and getting this error:

```
The primary reference "MySql.Data, Version=6.10.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d, processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5".
```

I am not sure which version is suitable for .NET 4.5

Comment: Is there a reason not to move to the current version of the framework?

Comment: well I created a new project in VS2015 and latest solution was .NET4.5, but in any case what will be the version with 4.5

Comment: target your project to 4.5.2.  Donwnload it if you don't have it

Answer (score 1):

The reason is .NET 4.5.2 is a drop in replacement for 4.5. 4.5 doesn't know about 4.5.2. 
As soon as you install a dll referencing 4.5.2, your 4.5 projects are compiled using the 4.5.2 Framework and it now knows about 4.5.2 and complains. Refer to this link:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connectors/en/connector-net-versions.html

As per this:

```
6.10    .Net Version required is 4.5.2 for VS 2013 / 2015 / 2017, .NET Core 1.1 for VS 2015 / 2017
6.10.5 (and later): .NET Core 2.0 for VS 2017 15.0.3 (or later)
```

However, 7.0 or 8.0 requirement is:

```
7.0 is  4.5.x for VS 2013 / 2015 / 2017, .NET Core 1.1 for VS 2015 / 2017
```

So, need to install 7.0 or 8.0 mysql version connector or change the target framework to 4.5.2.